# to show characteristic subgroup is normal in G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

> If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $H$ a characteristic subgroup of $N$ (i.e., $\sigma(H)=H$ for all $\sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(N)$). Show that $H$ is normal in $G$.

[image]

Does one needs to show that $\sigma(gHg^{-1})=gHg^{-1}$ for every g in G. Would that imply H is normal? is there a alternative way?

Comment: Hint $\sigma : N \to N$ defined by $n \mapsto gng^{-1}$ is an automorphism of $N$ for every $g \in G$. (why?)

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation). I have edited your post. You can edit it further, if needed, and when you are satisfied, you can remove the picture.

Answer (score 4):

The other answerer seems to have missed the subtlety that $H$ is not necessarily characteristic in $G$, only in $N$. However, an inner automorphism of $G$ leaves $N$ invariant and induces an automorphism on $N$. Since $H$ is characteristic in $N$, $H$ is also left invariant, hence $H$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: you are totally right ... I somehow read the question all too fast and was misleaded by only looking at the title :)

Comment: @M.U. I figured. Your answer is indeed correct given the somewhat misleading title. Let me know if you edit your answer so I can remove the criticism from mine! (I'm on a cell phone so it doesn't update automatically.)

Answer (score 2):

Normal subgroups are *by definition* exactly those subgroups which are invariant under inner automorphisms, that is automorphisms of the form $x \mapsto g x g^{-1}$ for some fixed $g \in G$. Thus a characteristic subgroup, i.e. a subgroup which is invariant under *all* automorphims, is trivially normal.